# qwebview vs javafx2 webview?

Tags: swing, qt, webview, awt, javafx

Both are powered by WebKit. I want to know if anyone out there has used both to know if in the areas of cross platform support and web page rendering, which is more mature and works better?

In particular I would like to know which one deserves time investment, seeing that support has discontinued for the QT counterpart, and seeing Oracle revitalizing support for JavaFX 2.0 has got me curious.

Which should you work with in embedding a browser view in Java Swing application that still is fully cross platform and is able to render Javascript and HTML5 well?

UPDATE: It's not too critical that HTML5 is supported but for the future, I think this is beneficial. What I would like to really see is true **cross platform support** (will the browser component work across Windows, Mac, and Linux) and **accurate web page rendering** (able to render Javascript, GWT applications, flash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Answer is QWebview.
I use JavaFX 2.0 develop two application,about 10K code line.I found JavaFX WebKit provide no API for plugin/MIME/link policy,and so on.
JavaFx is not so mature as Qt.

Comment: is QWebview cross platform across windows, mac, and linux?

Comment: Yes, it's cross platform on all platforms you mentioned, plus all the mobile platforms Qt supports.

Comment: Re comment above... Although getting a J2SE runtime might be a problem for some mobile platforms.
Re support discontinued for Qt counterpart... That doesn't mean QtJambi stopped working maybe some project statistics will help http://www.ohloh.net/p/qt-jambi March 2009 was the date official support stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Ive used both. The JavaFx view is good enought for rendering content but not good enough for hosting a JS application as a webshell. QWebView clearly is good enough, it is used by RStudio.